# Proving a Function is Strictly Greater than Another Using the Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[0,1]→\mathbb R$ and $g:[0,1]→\mathbb R$ be differentiable with $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Prove $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x\in (0,1]$

There only seems to be a related theorem, but only applies if $f'(x)=g'(x)$. I think it might be modifiable to fit this case. The theorem states:

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and that $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$. Then there is a real number $k$ such that $f(x)=g(x)+k$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

So, we want the case that $f'(x)>g'(x)$. Although, I'm not sure if I would use this theorem for this problem. Do I have to use IVT or construct a new function?

Comment: What can you say about a function whose derivative is positive everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h:=f-g$, then $h(0)=0$ and $h'(x)=f'(x) -g'(x) >0.$ Hence $h$ is strictly increasing, thus, for $x \in (0,1]$ we have

$h(x) >h(0)=0$, hence $f(x) >g(x).$

Comment: Guess I was just over thinking it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h=f-g$. Then $h$ is an increasing function (because its derivative is positive) so $h(x) > h(0)=f(0)-g(0)=0$ for $x >0$.  Hence $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x>0$